# How do I patch Minecraft's LWJGL libraries?

Tags: minecraft

I just downloaded a free version of minecraft and I also downloaded JDK 6 and 7/JRE 7. I can open minecraft perfectly and log in but after it installs updates, it stays at a black screen. I need to update my lwjgl files but there is no .bin folder in my minecraftSP.jar folder. Any tips? [image: screenshot of folder]

That is what my minecraft folder contains.

Comment: You don't put the libraries in the .jar file.  You normally put them in the "/username/.minecraft/bin", replacing "username" with your Ubuntu username.  I also aren't familiar with having it called "MinecraftSP.jar".  Did you download Minecraft from http://minecraft.net ?

Comment: Well, I'm cheap and don't want to buy it (I will later on though) I got it for free for Ubuntu. But the lwgjgl files were outdated. I got them now.

Comment: You will still need to buy it in order to go on multiplayer.  All the Ubuntu apps are just launchers for your convenience (I'm cheap and just don't use them).  In order for you to legally play the game you need to purchase it from http://minecraft.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Patching LWJGL in Minecraft (Linux)

**Download the LWJGL files**

1. Go to the [LWJGL download page](http://lwjgl.org/download.php) and download the latest stable release.
2. Open the .zip in Archive Manager.
3. The jars are found in "jar" and the natives are found in "natives/linux"

**Patch the LWJGL files by doing the following**

1. Open your home directory (You can usually just do this by opening the File Manager).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden folders.
3. Open ".minecraft" and open the "bin" folder.
4. Copy "jinput.jar", "lwjgl.jar" and "lwjgl_util.jar" from the "jar" folder.
5. Now open up the "natives" folder and copy  "ibjinput-linux.so", "libjinput-linux64.so", "liblwjgl.so", "liblwjgl64.so", "libopenal.so", "libopenal64.so" from "natives/linux".

Answer (score 0):

Try this [script](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/463570-update-lwjglsh-updates-your-lwjgl-for-linux-and-mac/), it worked for me.