# How can I make a Minecraft server on Lubuntu (any version)

Tags: minecraft

I tried for a few hours today on making a minecraft server. None of the videos on Youtube worked for me and everything just said there was an error while trying to open the files. As I went to Minecraft.net I clicked all the downloads, they downloaded but nothing opened. I have Java 6 installed and it is my defult opener for files. Can someone please give me a link to making a server on Lubuntu that worked for them?

```
                            Thanks in advance 
                                           ~Sloth
```

Comment: Do you want a vanilla Minecraft server as provided straight from Mojang, or would you like an easily extensible one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Minecraft (Server)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225471/how-to-install-minecraft-server)

Answer (score 3):

## **For a vanilla, straight-up Mojang issued server**

Download the Minecraft server from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.8.9/minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar). Now, from a command line, issue the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/server/folder
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft-server.1.8.9.jar nogui
```

The server will attempt to start and create a few necessary files. However, it will abruptly stop and say that you need to agree to the EULA. Open the newly created `eula.txt` file in your favorite editor, read through the agreement, and change `eula=false` to `eula=true`. Now, you can also edit the `server.properties` file to change the settings on your server.

Finally, open a command line and reissue the same commands as above. This time, your server will start and you will be good to go!

Comment: Note: if you want to use the GUI for issuing administrative commands instead of the command line, you can omit that last `nogui` flag in the command above.

Answer (score 0):

## **For an easily extensible Server, use Spigot**

**Spigot** is a modified version of the Minecraft server with TONS of plug-ins available to extend the game for your visitors. Plugins are easy to install, all you have to do is copy the downloaded plugin `.jar` file into your Spigot Plugins folder and restart the server. However, it requires a little more work to set-up and get going. First, I suggest you make a new directory to hold everything in. We'll call it `/home/user/Spigot`.

```
mkdir /home/user/Spigot
cd /home/user/Spigot
sudo apt-get install git
git config --global --unset core.autocrlf
wget https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar
java -jar BuildTools.jar
```

This process will take a while, as it is building the Spigot file. Once it is done, you will have a finished `spigot.jar` file in your directory.  Running it from now on will be as easy as:

```
cd /home/user/Spigot
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar spigot.jar nogui
```

The first time you run it, it will stop and say you need to agree to the EULA. Open up `/home/user/Spigot/eula.txt` in your favorite editor, and change `eula=false` to `eula=true`. Now, you are up and running. Feel free to search the web for Spigot Plug-ins to really customize your server!