# How to install Minecraft on PowerPC Lubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, mac, minecraft, powerpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly install and troubleshoot Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client)

I'm using the PowerPC version and also using an iMac G3 with nearly a gig of RAM and a 40GB Hard Drive as well as a new WiFi card.

How do I install Minecraft on this machine?