# Minecraft doesn't start on Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, java, lubuntu, minecraft

I've Installed OpenJDK 6, opened the jar with java by right clicking, but it doesnt do anything

What am I missing?

I've also tried java -jar Minecraft.jar with sudo, didn't worked :(

Comment: "Didn't worked" is such an informative description of the problem :) Expect helpful detailed answers... http://askubuntu.com/search?q=lwjgl

Comment: Do you receive any output on your terminal when you try `java -jar Minecraft.jar`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client/225433#225433

Answer (score 0):

Is the jar marked as executable? Right click on the jar file and check the execution permissions, or run

```
sudo chmod a+x Minecraft.jar
```

in the terminal.