# lagging minecraft

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, opengl, minecraft

I've started playing minecraft, on my windows pc it works flawless but when playing on my ubuntu laptop it runs verry slow. I allready put all minecraft settings to minimal, i'm running oracle java 7 and opengl is supported. this are my specs:

- lenovo Thinkpad X61s
- Ubuntu 12.10 64bit
- gnome-shell
- 4G RAM
- CPU: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU L7500 @ 1.60GHz × 2
- GPU: Intel® 965GM
- 64G SSD

Appart from my gpu it looks like decent specs to me, is it just the gpu that slows it down or could i do something to speed it up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed any drivers for your GPU?

Comment: I added some intel driver ppa's, but no packages where updated. i didn't install any packages manually

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client?rq=1

Comment: tried the steps but still hanging at 6-7 fps (see screenshot: http://ubuntuone.com/76J2FflQs8lkwq9SHNGbkt)

Comment: How much ram are you giving to your client? the recommeded amout of ram to play Vanilla is about 2GB also if you cannot dedicate that much ram to the client as requested above is it use optifine. i hope i have enhanced you gaming experiance :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try give it more RAM, this is how I did it:

```
-Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
```

Comment: Its in the JVM arguments: https://gyazo.com/b6a03aa7bec9232697b26eaa629f6344

Comment: This worked for me. I upped `-Xmx1G` to `2G` and my FPS went from 17-24 to 34-60. Now if only I had an actual graphics card..

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to try is Optifine, a minecraft lagg stop which lets you customize the game settings even more into depth. just google it and download the version for whatever version of minecraft you have, then mark the file as executable ( in the properties menu (right click) ) an then run. it will install optifine then run minecraft launcher, then choose the optifine minecraft version (Ex: optifine 1.8.1) and run. once that is done, go to settings and explore the settings and tweak them. this should work, it did for me, Good luck :)