# How do I remove Oracle Java 7 from Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, java, uninstall, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly install and troubleshoot Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client)

I currently got Ubuntu 11.10 installed on my laptop. And yesterday, I got Java 7. Before I got java 7, my Minecraft worked 100%. But after getting Java 7, my minecraft stopped working. So can you guys PLEASE find a way for me to 100% remove Java 7 from my system and get java 6 back!!

Comment: There's a section in the accepted answer in the duplicate question regarding troubleshooting issue that you should read.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need ORACLE Java, you can switch to Icedtea Open JDK.
But to your problem:
To completely uninstall a package just type into an terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge PACKAGENAME
```

in fact of Oracle java it's

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
```

and then install jre6 again

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Are you sure, you have Oracle Java installed? Because from Ubuntu 10.10 the Oracle Java isn't a part of the package-sources anymore... Did you install it manually?

Comment: I manually installed Java 7 not knowing it will stop me from using Minecraft. Ever since getting Java 7, it has installed Oracle Java 7 Runtime. And when I use OpenJDK 6 for minecraft, it won't work. Before java 7, the OpenJDK 6 worked for minecraft. Help me plz