# Minecraft bug on 12.10?

Tags: minecraft

I'm having issues running minecraft on 12.10. It loads up the log in screen, after I click 'log in' it goes to a black screen.

Comment: Is Java installed? Which version? Is a 3D graphics driver installed? You need these to run minecraft

Answer (score 1):

This is the definitive guide for Minecraft Installation issues

[How to install Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client)