# Minecraft Help!

Tags: 12.10, java, lubuntu, games, minecraft

So this is what I get when I Login to MineCraft on a 32 bit system 1.7 gig ram and 2.8 ghz prossesor:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Ooh. Shiny.

Time: 14/03/13 9:07 AM
Description: Failed to start game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:782)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:871)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:782)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:764)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:233)
    at avp.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:505)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 3.5.0-25-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_17, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 3996512 bytes (3 MB) / 30793728 bytes (29 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -Xmx1024m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    LWJGL: 2.8.3
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

That what I get.... I am usually a guy who fixes everything himself but I recently installed Lubuntu and... am a newbie.

All replies appreciated :)

Comment: Checkout this guide http://askubuntu.com/a/225433/75967 it covers most things