# Java can't launch minecraft, these errors happen. Using Java Oracle

Tags: java, minecraft

These errors happen when I launch minecraft, First error happens when I launch the login menu ( It still boots up ). Second when I actually launch the game.

```
Landswimmer@linux-99vz:~/Documents/Minecraft/Vanilla> java -jar minecraft.jar 
asdf
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Landswimmer/.minecraft/lastlogin (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at net.minecraft.LoginForm.readUsername(LoginForm.java:110)
        at net.minecraft.LoginForm.<init>(LoginForm.java:55)
        at net.minecraft.LauncherFrame.<init>(LauncherFrame.java:23)
        at net.minecraft.LauncherFrame.main(LauncherFrame.java:167)
        at net.minecraft.MinecraftLauncher.main(MinecraftLauncher.java:13)

Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/Landswimmer/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: /home/Landswimmer/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:69)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.G(SourceFile:1985)
        at awe.<init>(SourceFile:20)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(SourceFile:76)
        at avv.<init>(SourceFile:38)
        at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftApplet.init(SourceFile:38)                           
        at net.minecraft.Launcher.replace(Launcher.java:136)                                  
        at net.minecraft.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:79)
```

Comment: You don't launch the Minecraft file directly, you launch the Minecraft launcher instead. Also mention the version of Minecraft in your answer as there is a new launcher as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is when I launch the game from the launcher, it downloads the files and then black screens and that error happens. I opened it this way to see an error log.

Comment: Checkout this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client/225433#225433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Oracle isn't the best solution for Minecraft. I'd suggest using OpenJDK instead. You can see how you install OpenJDK for Ubuntu, [here](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

Luis Alvarado's explanation (as Meer Bong suggested in the last comment) is very complicated, and you don't need to install Minecraft via Wine, to make it work.

You simply download the Launcher from [Minecraft's website](http://minecraft.net/) (the file called minecraft.jar) and right click it, and open it via OpenJDK. Then, from the launcher menu, click the options button, and press the button "Force Update". Then it should work perfectly. It worked perfect for me, and I've had no trouble with Minecraft whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but also Why is OpenJDK better for minecraft than oracle?

Comment: I don't really know, I have recently learned that there isn't that big of a difference, but this is based on my experience

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use Oracle's Java for certain things to work with the Sage math program. If you install Java using the instructions here http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDE-on-Ubuntu-Linux or here http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDE-on-Ubuntu-Linux (if you need JDK) then you should be able to type

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

You don't have a convenient right click option like with openjdk but it works fine for me like that. I know this is an old thread but this is the first link Google returns as a result and it didn't have the info I needed as I was aware that it works with openjdk but needed/wanted it to work with Oracle Java. Which it does.