# No Sound in Minecraft 1.6.2

Tags: 13.04, sound, 64-bit, java, minecraft

Since the update to 1.5 to 1.6, I haven't had any sound. I've tried the fallowing:

Deleted .minecraft folder
Redownloaded the new launcher
Replaced lwjgl with the version used in 1.5 (doesn't work because new launcher auto-updates it back to the latest)
Changed resource packs.
F3+S
Checked sound files and options

None of which fixed it. :(
From what I gather, this isn't the same issue some folks on Windows have had, because none of their fixes work for me. So I assume this is a Linux issue with java.

This is on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, and I'm using the latest openjdk.

Comment: Hi RPG Master (D&D!!) did you follow this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client

Comment: Just tested vanilla 1.6.0, 1.6.1 and 1.6.2. All working correctly and with sound and HORSES! Try them without any resource packs and keep on adding until you find why do not have sound. For me I added a couple and still have sound. Tested on 3 PCs.

Comment: Luis: Looking at that guide, all the useful info, like updating lwjgl, has been broken with the new update.

Comment: Luis, are any of those computers running 64bit?

Comment: 1 of them is. If you like we can go here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9527/quick-help