# Minecraft running slow

Tags: 13.04, minecraft, troubleshooting

Guys i had installed ubuntu 13.10 and minecraft was running normal 30 fps.
one day i had black screen problems so i reinstall my linux (format) and minecraft was running on 12 to 14 fps.
i have installed hava 7,java 8, openjdk 7 and everything requires but minecraft stil slow
what to do. dont tell me abou pc specs because my pc is expensive so i dont have problem with specs:

- core 13 3.30 ghz
- Radeon hd 7850 oc
- 12gb ram 1600 mhz

Comment: I have i5 3.4 ghz, gtx 650 ti, 8 GB RAM and I run minecraft at around 300 fps never go under 200 fps... What settings do you have in minecraft?

Comment: everything to full

Comment: well that explains the low performance....

Comment: no, before reinstalling linux i had aroud 30-40 fps and windows around 3000 fps

Comment: Can you add the output of `file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac` to your question?

Comment: Can you also add the output of `file $(which java javac)` to your question?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad GPU driver. If your ATI card isn't being used, the i3 integrated graphics + processor can't do much more than 20fps on low settings. Make sure to upgrade your ati drivers and everything should work amazingly. You can google how to, you should easily find it!

Also, having 12gb of ram, you sure could launch the game with more ram than by default. You can now change it directly in the game launcher in the profile editor using the "JVM Arguments". (Eg. "-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m" would make the game run with 2gb of ram)

Have fun, Minecraft works like a charm on Linux. I get about 200 more frames per second than I get on Windows.

EDIT (Easier to read than in the comments):

Make sure to delete any drivers first:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Then install Catalyst 13.1 running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

That should work, good luck!

Comment: well the settings are all on full, how do you explain it now?

Comment: i dont want to add more ram to mc because i have server

Comment: well do you remember black screen problem?

Comment: i had that problems from ati drivers

Comment: ooh and what is better jdk 7 or jre 8

Comment: Then you probably installed the wrong drivers. Don't use Ubuntu's update ones.

I edited my answer with the needed lines.

That should work, good luck!

Comment: JDK = Java Dev Kit / JRE = Java Runtime Environment. The dev kit includes JRE, but you don't really need it. About the version, I don't think you would notice a big differene. Both are supported.

Comment: do i need reboot after that 3 commands?

Comment: Yes. After the reboot, the driver should be active, tell me if the performences are any better!

Comment: Yes i got 50-88 fps but i was very scared on the users screen for doing black screen problem again

Comment: Yeah, Linux can be a little scary at its first uses, but you'll get used to it. And once you learn how to use it properly, you'll never want to go back to Windows or OSx haha

Glad it helped! Also try adding more ram as I said in my answer, it might boost the performences a little more! Have fun!