# Can't make Minecraft executable

Tags: minecraft

I've tried lots of things, but it just wouldn't work.  I'm going to properties
and then to permissions but the executable check box isn't there. All there is in the permissions tab is:

```
general emblems permissions
owner: name
access: ethier (none,read only,write only,read and write)
group: name
access: ethier (none,read only,write only,read and write)
others: etheir (none,read only,write only,read and write)
```

How to install Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the Properties window in the Permissions tab there should a line (the last line) that says: *Execute: Allow executing file as program*. Put a check mark in the checkbox to the left of where it says: *Allow executing file as program*.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client/225433#225433) by Luis Alvarado is a complete guide for the installation of Minecraft.