# Trying to use the minecraft installer

Tags: minecraft

I just got ubuntu 13.10 today and I am trying to install minecraft, I saw the way that is suggested here: [How to install Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client) and tried it and it worked till when I opened minecraft, it would show that it was running, but I couldn't see minecraft its self. Did I forget to type a command that shows minecraft on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that answer is crazy overcomplicated.  All you need to do is follow the simple instructions on minecraft.net: download Minecraft.jar, and run it with `java -jar Minecraft.jar`.  If you don't already have java installed, then install it with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile Minecraft.jar I get this when I try to run it.

Comment: @KnightZack, you need to be in the directory where you downloaded the file to, or specify the path to it.

Comment: These are no longer the instructions posted on the Minecraft website.  Which is basically "download an run a .deb file".