# How do I install the Ubuntu Software Center on my Lubuntu 15.04 using the Terminal?

Tags: 15.04, minecraft

[How to install Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-install-minecraft-client/225433#225433) That link doesnt help. I can't install Java or something. I need a video. Does anyone have a video I cant watch? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Lubuntu software center should be already in you system, is it not?

Comment: What is it you want to install? The Software Centre? Minecraft? Java?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-center`

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle Java 8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

And use the `minecraft-installer`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Once installed, run Minecraft from the menu / Dash, login with your Minecraft account and the installation should start automatically.

<sub>[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/easily-install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-via.html)</sub>