# How do I get Minecraft on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I can't seem to figure out how to get minecraft on Ubuntu 14.04 please help! thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Minecraft (Client)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-install-minecraft-client)

Answer (score 0):

You can go in to the app store and get something that is really close to minecraft (I honestly like it better than minecraft), it is called minetest. It works really well and is amazing!

Comment: Are you buying minecraft? For Ubuntu?